# #define statement for address of memory

Tags: c, pointers, signal-processing

What does this #define statement do? It is used to define an address of memory. But I don't understand the (uint32_t *) part

```
#define GPxDAT (uint32_t *) 0x6FC0
```

Comment: Given the lack of context, all there is to say about that is that it replaces every occurrence of `GPxDAT` in your code with `(uint32_t *) 0x6FC0`.

Comment: `(uint32_t *)` forces `0x6FC0` to be the address of a `uint32_t`.

Comment: `(uint32_t *)` is casting that hex number to be a pointer to `uint32_t`

Comment: Likely in an embedded system, `GPxDAT` is intended to be used as `*GPxDAT = some_value;`, writing the `some_value` at memory location `0x6FC0`, or `content = *GPxDAT`, reading the value from the memory location `0x6FC0`, interpreting that value as an `uint32_t` type. In any case, it would be better to fully parenthesize the expression in macro definition like: `#define GPxDAT ((uint32_t *) 0x6FC0)`

Answer (score 3):

It is usually used to access hardware registers mapped into the address space, or some particular memory addresses

Hardware registers should be defined as `volatile` as registers can change without any program activity (as they are changed by the hardware).

```
#define GPIOREGA ((volatile uint32_t *) 0x6FC0)
```

then you can assign or read this memory location (`*GPIOREGA = something; something = *GPIOREGA` )

Sometimes much more complex data structures are used this way (example from the STM32 headers)

```
#define __IO volatile

typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t MODER;    /*!< GPIO port mode register,               Address offset: 0x00      */
  __IO uint32_t OTYPER;   /*!< GPIO port output type register,        Address offset: 0x04      */
  __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;  /*!< GPIO port output speed register,       Address offset: 0x08      */
  __IO uint32_t PUPDR;    /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,  Address offset: 0x0C      */
  __IO uint32_t IDR;      /*!< GPIO port input data register,         Address offset: 0x10      */
  __IO uint32_t ODR;      /*!< GPIO port output data register,        Address offset: 0x14      */
  __IO uint32_t BSRR;     /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset register,      Address offset: 0x18      */
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;     /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C      */
  __IO uint32_t AFR[2];   /*!< GPIO alternate function registers,     Address offset: 0x20-0x24 */
} GPIO_TypeDef;

#define PERIPH_BASE           0x40000000U /*!< Peripheral base address in the alias region                                */

#define AHB1PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x00020000U)
#define GPIOA_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0000U)

#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)
```

And you can use it is as any normal pointer

```
GPIOA -> MODER |= (1 << 15);
```

Comment: Good answer, but I think you could clarify the bit about registers changing without any program activity with a word or two - it can be confusing to a beginner ("How can that happen?") , i.e. the kind of person this answer is targeting.

Answer (score 0):

The `(uint32_t *)` *part*  is what is called a *cast*, it converts the integer number `0x6FC0` to a pointer(an address) to an `unsigned` integer, 32bits wide (which is what the `uint32_t` type represents.)  Basically a type conversion to a pointer to an unsigned integer.  In my opinion, the expression is not completely safe.  While the cast operator is high precedence, it should be written as:

```
#define  GPxDAT ((uint32_t *) 0x6FC0)
```

rounding the whole expression in parenthesis, so it will not fail, wherever you put it.

Writing this kind of defines, you can access `GPxDAT[0]` as a 32bit unsigned integer at the address `0x6fc0`, `GPxDAT[1]` as the next 32bit address (above the previous one) all of them based at the address represented by the number.